# Android Https error 400 can't insert Authorization

Tags: java, android

I am trying this in Android Studio, but the line

```java
 connection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);
```

is not working. How can I add the authorization needed in order to connect correctly?

```java
        HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) leaveUrl.openConnection();
        // Create the SSL connection
        SSLContext sc;
        sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sc.init(null, null, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        connection.setSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());

        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslsocketfactory);
        String basicAuth = Base64.encodeToString(sessionKey.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        connection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);
        connection.connect();

        msg = String.valueOf(connection.getResponseCode());
```